# Speeding up Go builds with go 1.10 build cache in Docker containers

Tags: docker, go

I have a Go project with a large `vendor/` directory which almost never changes.

I am trying to use the new [go 1.10](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10) **build cache** feature to speed up my builds in Docker engine locally.

Avoiding recompilation of my `vendor/` directory would be enough optimization. So I'm trying to do Go equivalent of this common Dockerfile pattern for Python:

```
FROM python
COPY requirements.txt .              # <-- copy your dependency list
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  # <-- install dependencies
COPY ./src ...                       # <-- your actual code (everything above is cached)
```

Similarly I tried:

```
FROM golang:1.10-alpine
COPY ./vendor ./src/myproject/vendor
RUN go build -v myproject/vendor/... # <-- pre-build & cache "vendor/"
COPY . ./src/myproject
```

However this is giving "cannot find package" error (likely because you cannot build stuff in vendor/ directly normally either).

Has anyone been able to figure this out?

Comment: A you said, you can't build a vendor package directly. Why not just build `myproject`?

Comment: Because I have 300+ vendored packages (3.8M lines of code) I have to rebuild everytime (the result is not cached), and `myproject` is only 530 lines of code. :)

Comment: but building mypackage will build and cache all the vendored packages, which seems exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @JimB but in order for Docker's cache to be effective, building all the vendored packages and building the project itself need to be 2 separate steps, thus creating 2 layers in the Docker image.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that works for me:

```
FROM golang:1.10-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/local/go/src/github.com/myorg/myproject/
COPY vendor vendor
RUN find vendor -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -exec sh -c 'go install -i github.com/myorg/myproject/{}/... || true' \;
COPY main.go .
RUN go build main.go
```

It makes sure the vendored libraries are installed first. As long as you don't change a library, you're good.

Comment: This works for some repos and speeds things up! However, if _your vendored packages also have a vendor/ directory_ they're actually being built at the last `RUN go build` you mentioned (add `-v` to see). Example of this is the package: `github.com/myuser/myproj/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/settings/v1alpha1`. So it's a hacky/half-solution. But thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `go install -i ./vendor/...`.

Consider the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM    golang:1.10-alpine

ARG     APP
ENV     PTH $GOPATH/src/$APP
WORKDIR $PTH

# Pre-compile vendors.
COPY    vendor/ $PTH/vendor/
RUN     go install -i ./vendor/...

ADD     . $PTH/

# Display time taken and the list of the packages being compiled.
RUN     time go build -v
```

You can test it doing something like:

```
docker build -t test --build-arg APP=$(go list .) .
```

On the project I am working on, without pre-compile, it takes ~12sec with 90+ package each time, after, it take ~1.2s with only 3 (only the local ones).

If you still have "cannot find package", it means there are missing vendors. Re-run `dep ensure` should fix it.

An other tip, unrelated to Go is to have your `.dockerignore` start with `*`. i.e. ignore everything and then whitelist what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because my `vendor/` directory is "pruned" (doesn't contain sub packages that are not used in my program). Therefore doing `go install -i ./vendor/...` builds a package like `github.com/alex/repo/foo`, which needs `github.com/alex/repo/bar` but it doesn't exist in my `vendor/` because it is pruned. However my program compiles fine without `bar`.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google doesn't the linker/compiler already prune unused code? Have you checked to see if there are reasonable tradeoffs between pruning vendor as you have done, and not pruning, but taking advantage of build caching?

Answer (score 1):

As of Go 1.11, you would use go modules to accomplish this;

```
FROM golang
WORKDIR /src/myproject
COPY go.mod go.sum ./             # <-- copy your dependency list
RUN go mod download               # <-- install dependencies
COPY . .                          # <-- your actual code (everything above is cached)
```

As long as `go.sum` doesn't change, the image layer created by `go mod download` shall be reused from cache.

Answer (score 0):

Using `go mod download` alone didn't do the trick for me.

What ended up working for me was to leverage [buildkit](https://%20https://github.com/moby/buildkit#building-a-dockerfile-with-experimental-features-like-run---mounttypebindcachetmpfssecretssh)  to mount Go's build cache.

[This](https://vsupalov.com/buildkit-cache-mount-dockerfile/) was the article that lead me to this feature.

My Dockerfile looks something like this

```
FROM golang AS build

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . ./
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build \ 
    go build -o /my-happy-app
```

For local development this did quite a different for me, changing buildtimes from 1.5 minutes to 3 seconds.

I'm using colima (to run Docker on my Mac. Just mentioning this since I'm not using Docker for Mac, but it should work just the same) with

```
colima version 0.4.2
git commit: f112f336d05926d62eb6134ee3d00f206560493b

runtime: docker
arch: x86_64
client: v20.10.9
server: v20.10.11
```

And golang 1.17, so this is not a 1.10 specific answer.

I took this setup from docker compose's cli dockerfile [here](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/blob/main/Dockerfile).

Your mileage may vary.